# replace all non alphanumerics with underscore

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
second_arg="${second_arg/[^[:alnum:]]/_}"
```

if I do this:

```
second_arg="foo::"
second_arg="${second_arg/[^[:alnum:]]/_}"
echo "$second_arg"
```

then I get:

```
foo_:
```

how do I replace all instances of non-alphanumerics? I tried a global switch like this:

```
 second_arg="${second_arg/[^[:alnum:]]/_/g}"
```

but that didn't work, I ended up getting:

```
foo_:/g
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or, if you want to stick with bash's variable expansion features, use **two** forward-slashes to replace every match with the replacement:

```
second_arg="${second_arg//[^[:alnum:]]/_}"
                         ^------ here
```

Comment: thanks do you happen to know what this is called?

Comment: [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) under "${parameter/pattern/string}", where you probably already were, but hidden in this: "If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string."

Comment: The idea is that the "first" and "last" forward slashes are syntactically required, so the "second" slash is a "pattern that begins with /".

Comment: No, a pattern that start with slash is `\/pattern`. The second `/` has a syntactic meaning: repeated (like g in sed `s///g`).

Answer (score 5):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo 'This is a test; specifically it is test number 25!' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/_/g'
This_is_a_test__specifically_it_is_test_number_25_
```

Comment: for some reason I saw people using `sed -r` instead of `sed` not sure what the difference is, but the -r option is not available on MacOS.

Comment: `sed -r` is functionally the same as `sed -E`.  `-E` is not needed for this usage, however -- the above example was tested on a Mac, as it happens.

Comment: I have to support both MacOS and Linux so I need something x-platform. Is there a `x-platform` tag/label for questions on unix.stackexchange?  Right now this seems to work: `second_arg="${second_arg//[^[:alnum:]]/_}"`

Comment: note the double forward slash instead of the single forward slash

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Jeff Schaller's answer, there are various things that "search and replace" parameter substition can do:

Given: `s="_one_two_one_two"`

1. replace the *first* "two"

   ```
   $ echo ${s/two/X}
   _one_X_one_two
   ```
2. replace *all* "two"

   ```
   $ echo ${s//two/X}
   _one_X_one_X
   ```
3. replace "two" if it is anchored *at the end of the string*

   ```
   $ echo ${s/%two/X}
   _one_two_one_X
   ```
4. replace "one" if it is anchored *at the start of the string* (it is not, no replacement)

   ```
   $ echo ${s/#one/X}
   _one_two_one_two
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In bash (as you are using) a `${arg/one/two}` will replace only the first occurrence of `on`. To replace all double the first `/` as this `${arg/one/two}`, so, for your case:

```
arg=${arg//[^[:alnum:]]/_}
```

The second slash could be changed to `#` to mean start and to `%` to mean end.

If the string is:

```
➤ a=one_two_/one_two_one
```

To change the first instance (only) of `one`:

```
➤ echo ${a/one/xXx}
xXx_two_/one_two_one
```

The first instance of `two`:

```
➤ echo ${a/two/xXx}
one_xXx_/one_two_one
```

The string `one` at the start of the parameter:

```
➤ echo ${a/#one/xXx}
xXx_two_/one_two_one
```

The string `one` at the end of the parameter:

```
➤ echo ${a/%one/xXx}
one_two_/one_two_xXx
```

The string `/one` (start with a slash):

```
➤ echo ${a/\/one/xXx}
one_two_xXx_two_one
```

All the repetitions of `one`:

```
➤ echo ${a//one/xXx}
xXx_two_xXx_two_xXx
```